# How to make CSS for search results

Tags: html, css, search, input

How to make CSS for searching results like this
[image]

the result in infront of the other element html, in contains link like this

```
<li><a href=""></li>
<li><a href=""></li>
<li><a href=""></li>
```

Thankyou Experts !

Comment: You want to search from the database? or just style your page like the one in the image?

Comment: check this too http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Answer (score -2, accepted):

do you want search suggestion? or if you want suggestion on input like as providing image so it's generated by browser it's not user generated if you want user generated so `<ul><li></li></ul>` is best for it. otherwise on your image input suggestion is browser generated not user generated its from browser cache.

if it is generated by a ajax request or something, so it could be styled else you can not style such suggestions.

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="suggested_input">
<ul class="suggestions">
<li>option 1</li>
<li>option 2</li>
<li>option 3</li>
<li>option 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-group{
 width:250px;  /*as you want*/
 position:relative;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
ul.suggestions{
 width:100%; /* its width according to input width */
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 height:auto;
 display:none;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
/* if you want style so that's why i use "li a" also */
ul.suggestions li, 
ul.suggestions li a{
 background-color:#fff;
 color:#000;
 font-size:12px; /* according to your requirement */
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:0 10px;
 margin:0px;
 line-height:30px; /* according to your requirement */
 display:block;
}
ul.suggestions li:hover,
ul.suggestions li a:hover{
 background-color:#ccc;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:normal;
}
ul.suggestions li:hover .suggested_input{
 background-color:#FAFFBD;
 border:1px solid #3C8DBC;
}
.suggested_input:hover .suggestions{
display:block;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/rzwqsrs1/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP is asking about how to style it.

Comment: in his provided picture input suggestion is browser generated so he no need to style it. He want similar like image input suggestion

Comment: How do you know it is browser generated? Could be populated by an AJAX request?

Comment: if it is generated by a ajax request or something, so it could be styled else you can not style such suggestions. 
/*------------- style given edited answer ---------*/

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this css to each one choosing left or right

```
<style>
.right {
float: right;
width: 300px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
}
.left {
float: left;
width: 300px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```